# Postfix SMTP mail server External smtp relay

Tags: command-line, server, email, postfix, mail

How can I configure postfix smtp?

- External smtp relay
- Smtp authentication
- Email send rate limit
- Schedule emails

Answer (score 0):

If you go to https://help.ubuntu.com and enter "postfix" into the search box, you'll get a number of helpful articles, including this one https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix to help install and configure postfix.

Comment: Please remember to vote/accept my answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I've used SendGrid's free plan account and my office 365 outlook mailbox.

**External SMTP Server configuration**

1. Go to sendgrid and [register](https://signup.sendgrid.com/) a profile
2. Go to [Sender Authentication](https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/sender_auth/senders/new) and create a new sender ([Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvsHT.png))
   Specify some not-free email (I used office 365 Online account), so Sender could be verified by SendGrid.
3. Check your mailbox and click **Verify Single Sender** button in the letter ([Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXZIT.png))
4. Go to [SMTP Relay integration page](https://app.sendgrid.com/guide/integrate/langs/smtp) and create an apikey, you will put in postfix's `sasl_passwd` file ([Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0asZh.png)). Do not close a verification page till you insert it there and verify. After postfix settings have been applied with new api key added, postfix restarting and test email sending: [image]

**Postfix configuration:**

Install some packages and [configure postfix](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-18-04):

```
sudo apt install postfix mailutils
```

Configure `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file the next way, adding or modifying the next lines:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
compatibility_level = 2
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_security_level=may

smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level=encrypt
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = localhost.localdomain

alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost
relayhost = [smtp.sendgrid.net]:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
```

Create `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` file (api secret key would be gained further):

```
[smtp.sendgrid.net]:587 apikey:SG.kjaksdjkfajskdk_ASDk.lkjaoIO_Kjkoaofs3i99asfd_kkjasdof99882348IKII
```

Apply settings:

```
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
sudo systemctl restart postfix
```

**Test email sending during SendGrid's verification**

1. Click *Next Verify Integration* button. You'll be on *Let's test your integration* page.
2. Click the *Verify Integration* button
3. Run a different terminal window to see logs, using `journalctl -f` command
4. Run a command in a terminal to test mail sending, using **Single Sender** after `-r` parameter created in *External SMTP Server configuration* section.

   ```
    echo "Test Email message body" | mail -r xxxx@yyyy.onmicrosoft.com -s "Email test subject" zzzz@gmail.com
   ```

As a result, my gmail.com mailbox received a test letter. I've also sent it to my yahoo.com account and it also have been received into a Spam folder after a some time of deferring.